# Pip suddenly cant find or install any package

Tags: pip, pypi, python-packaging

Suddenly pip cant install or find any package, it cant even figure out its own version.
I reinstalled python multiple times, i have the latest version of python 3 and pip. I also tried to clear pip cache. Nothing works, this is really annoying...

Errors:

```
>pip install redblacktree
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement redblacktree (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for redblacktree
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip
```

```
>pip config list
freeze.user='yes'
global.index-url='http://pypi.org/simple'
global.trusted-host='pypi.org'
install.user='yes'
list.user='yes'
uninstall.user='yes'
```

Comment: Is your internet connection still good? What about your system clock?

Comment: What if you try `python -m pip install <whatever>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by locating the `pip.ini` config file and removing the line `index-url = http://pypi.org/simple`